# wordpress social login plugin: not pulling Facebook frinds list

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins

I'm using the wordpress social login plugin on one of my sites. It's been working perfectly fine for users registering on the site, but it's not pulling their friends/contacts.

As far as I can tell I've followed all the correct setup instructions for both the plugin and my Facebook app. I've scoured both stackoverflow and the plugin support forums for others having the same trouble to no avail.

Basically, when signing up with Facebook, the app is not requesting `user_friends` as one of it's permissions, which as far as I can tell is pretty much default?

Anyone out there perhaps have an idea of what I may be getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Facebook api [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) since v2.0:

> Friend list is no longer part of the default permission set and has
>   its own permission: Asking for access to a person's friend list is now
>   a separate permission that your app must request. The new permission
>   is called user_friends.

And from v2.3 (current):

[Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends)

> - A user access token with user_friends permission is required to view the current person's friends.
> - This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.
> - If a friend of the person declines the user_friends permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.